# Vorticity equations of incompressible Navier-Stokes equations in 2D

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

We know for incompressible Navier-Stokes equations, we have the vorticity equation: $$\omega_t - \Delta \omega + (u \cdot \nabla)\omega = (\omega \cdot \nabla)u$$

But for two dimensional space, $(u \cdot \nabla)\omega $. I don't see why after I plug in the expression of $\omega$. (Here $\omega = \partial_1 u_2 - \partial_2 u_1$)

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the 2D Navier-Stokes equations can be realised as a special kind of solution to 3D Navier-Stokes, namely one for which
$$ u(x,y,z) = (u_1(x,y),u_2(x,y),0) , \quad w(x,y,z)=\nabla \times u(x,y,z) =(0,0,\omega(x,y)).$$
Here, $\omega = \operatorname{curl}_{\text{2D}}(u_1,u_2). $ See for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#2D_flow_in_orthogonal_coordinates).

Plugging this into the above vorticity equation, we notice in particular that 
$$ w\cdot \nabla = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \omega  \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \partial_1 \\ \partial_2 \\ \partial_3  \end{pmatrix}  = \omega\partial_3$$
So since $u$ does not depend on $x_3$, the term $(w\cdot\nabla) u $ vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

In 2D case, the vorticity is a scalar, and the vortex stretching term $\omega\cdot\nabla u$ should disappear.